# Migration of .Net Project from Framework 1.1 to Framework 4.0 (Windows Application)

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, frameworks, migration, .net-1.1

I am a fresher working in Windows application using .Net Framework 1.1. We are going to migrate our Windows application from .Net Framework 1.1 to 4.0. What are all impacted when we migrate from 1.1 to 4.0 ? Please help and suggest me since i am new in this technology..

Answer (score 3):

here are the steps by msdn :

[Migrating .net 1.1 to 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956194.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is a Window application. So,is these steps same for window application?

Comment: ASP.Net is used for Web applications.

Comment: @Bhaskar you can ignore ASP.NET specific steps in that article, but most steps are universally applicable to all application types.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Karan Shah already shows the good link for you to explore. So please follow the common steps described in it.

Personally I suggest you pay attention to the obsolete warnings if there is  any in your case. Later .NET Frameworks do have better things offered, so you should carefully get rid of the obsolete stuffs ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling in 1.1 is another than 2.0 and higher
In 1.1 unhandled exceptions swallowed, and in 2.0 and higher this behavior was changed.
The unhandled exception, then, will result in an application crash.
You can configure behaviour in confuguration file